# "multi-dimensional" cyclotomic number

Tags: nt.number-theory, finite-fields, cyclotomic-fields

Let $F_q$ be the finite field with $q$ elements with characteristic $p$ and with $g$ being a primitive root. Let $N$ be a divisor of $q-1$ and let $C_0$ be the subgroup of $F_q^*$ with index $N$. Then we can define $C_j=g^jC_0$ for $1 \leq j \leq N-1$. $C_0, C_1, \ldots, C_{N-1}$ are usually called the $N$-th cyclotomic classes of $F_q$. A central problem in the theory of cyclotomy is to obtain formulas for the following cyclotomic numbers:
$$
c(i,j):=
\#\{x \in C_i: x+1 \in C_j\}.
$$
For example, when $-1$ is a power of $p$ modulo $N$, it is known that we have the so-called uniform cyclotomy, i.e. $c(i,j)$ is independent of $i,j$ (proved by L.D.Baumert,W.H.Mills, and Robert L.Ward in *Uniform cyclotomy,J. Number Theory 14 (1982), no. 1, 67–82.* )

I am wondering if there is some research on "multi-dimensional" cyclotomic number, for example if $-1$ is a power of $p$ modulo $N$, do we know something about the following 3-dimensional cyclotomic number
$$
\#\{x \in C_i: x+1 \in C_j, x+2 \in C_k\}?
$$

Any reference or comments would be appreciated!